# jQuery .submit( [callback] ) within .click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I hope that there is a simple explaination for this, but I haven't yet found it.

I am trying to trigger a form to submit on an event, and when that form submits it should have a callback. My code works when I just use the event to trigger .submit() without any submit callback, and the submit callback works outside of the event trigger, but I haven't managed to make them work at the same time.

My javascript is as follows:

```
$("#test_form #notabutton").click( function () {
    alert("Checkpoint 1");
    $('#test_form').submit( function( event ) {
        alert("Checkpoint 2");
        return;
    });
});
```

And my html:

```
<form id="test_form">
    <input type="checkbox" name="letter" value="Alpha">Alpha<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="letter" value="Bravo">Bravo
    <!-- <input type="submit" value="Submit"> -->
    <div id="notabutton" style="height:100px; width:100px; background-color:blue;"></div>
</form>
```

And here is a jsfiddle for good measure: http://jsfiddle.net/5bwGw/.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`.submit()` function](http://api.jquery.com/submit/), along with similar functions like `.click()`, can be used either to bind an action to an event or to trigger that event.

If you write `foo.submit();`, it acts as short-hand for `foo.trigger('submit');`

If however you write `foo.submit( function() { alert('boing'); } );`, it acts as a short-hand for `foo.on('submit', function() { alert('boing'); } );`

Personally, I try to avoid using the short-hands, and use `.on` (or in older code `.bind`) and `.trigger` directly, to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You are not triggering a submit, you are setting a function to run on submit.

The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) says nothing about a callback.

Comment: Looking over the API again, it looks like you are right. .submit() is apparently short for both .on('submit', handler) and .trigger('submit'), but not at the same time.